# How to make Flink job with huge state finish

Tags: apache-flink

We are running a Flink cluster to calculate historic terabytes of streaming data. The data calculation has a huge state for which we use keyed states - Value and Map states with RocksDb backend. At some point in the job calculation the job performance starts degrading, input and output rates drop to almost 0. At this point exceptions like 'Communication with Taskmanager X timeout error" can be seen in the logs, however the job is compromised even before.

I presume the problem we are facing has to the with the RocksDb's disk backend. As the state of the job grows it needs to access the Disk more often which drags the performance to 0. We have played with some of the options and have set some which make sense for our particular setup:

We are using the `SPINNING_DISK_OPTIMIZED_HIGH_MEM` predefined profile, further optimized with `optimizeFiltersForHits` and some other options which has somewhat improved performance. However not of this can provide a stable computation and on a job re-run against a bigger data set the job halts again.

What we are looking for is a way to modify the job so that it progresses at SOME speed even when the input and the state increases. We are running on AWS with limits set to around 15 GB for Task Manager and no limit on disk space.

Comment: I think you are more likely to get knowledgeable responses to this question on the flink-user mailing list than on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

using SPINNING_DISK_OPTIMIZED_HIGH_MEM will cost huge off-heap memory by memtable of RocksDB, Seeing as you are running job with memory limitation around 15GB, I think you will encounter the OOM issue, but if you choose the default predefined profile, you will face the write stall issue or CPU overhead by decompressing the page cache of Rocksdb, so I think you should increase the memory limitation.
and here are some post about Rocksdb FYI:
https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Memory-usage-in-RocksDB
https://www.ververica.com/blog/manage-rocksdb-memory-size-apache-flink